# ToLocaleDateString() workaround for IE & Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, internet-explorer

I was using a JS function to declare a var date that was the next available 1st day of the month. i.e. todays would be 11/01/2017(mm/dd/yyyy). The function was working perfectly however IE 11+ would not take it, and instead throw in some extra functions which the form would then reject as not being a valid date, however in Chrome it worked perfectly.

Ive changed the code to the following, which works on both browsers..

```
//Calculate and assign next available 1st day of the month
 var date = new Date();
 firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 1);
 firstDay = (new Date(firstDay).toLocaleString('en-US').replace(/[^ -~]/g,''));
```

however the output is: `11/1/2017,%2012:00:00%20AM..`. which is functionally correct as my form picks up the `"11/1/2017`" part, and ignores the rest, both on IE & Chrome, however how can I change the above code so it will just remove the "`,%2012:00:00%20AM`"? Its just a sake of tidying up the URL which is passing along user-data

Comment: I don't understand you just want to show 11/1/2017? If it is suppose to be used as a string does your variable firstDay has to be a Date for some reason? You could just write firstDay = date.getDate()  + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) '/' +  date.getFullYear(). Or you want something else?

Comment: Or maybe even 

firstDay = (new Date(firstDay).toLocaleString('en-US')).Substring(0, 10);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Date.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) accepts an [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Using_options) parameter allowing to declare how you want your output.

In your case you'll want `{day: 'numeric', month:'numeric', year:'numeric'}`:

```js
var date = new Date();
firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 1);
firstDay = new Date(firstDay).toLocaleString('en-US', {
      day: 'numeric',
      month: 'numeric',
      year: 'numeric'
    }).replace(/[^ -~]/g,'');
console.log(firstDay);
```

(Which will indeed be the same as [`Date.toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) without options)

Comment: Works perfectly, but IE wont take it, im getting an output on screen: Invalid GET Data, this is the initial problem I had with my last function, =‎11‎/‎1‎/‎2017.. if you copy paste that date, theres an invisible character before the '=', I noticed because i always have to hit backspace twice in the URL, and even on this comment box, is it possible to add  the .replace to the above code snippet?

Comment: @sanitizer sure, I added it back, I wasn't sure what it did and I haven't an IE under hands to experience that issue.

Comment: Tell me about it.. IE is a pain. Also, the addition of .replace sorted the problem and the above code snippet works perfectly on both chrome & IE ! Thank you

Comment: Also, that .replace(xxxx,' ') replaces the 'x' in this case with whats in ' ', that being a null so just wipes off any ^-~ etc

Answer (score 2):

You can use toLocaleDateString, this will give you just the date part in locale format.

```js
var d = new Date();

console.log(d.toLocaleDateString("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use

```
firstDay = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) '/' + date.getFullYear().
```

Or

```
 firstDay = new Date(firstDay).toLocaleString('en-US')
```